# How to run a command from the mongo shell in docker after having connected to an instance with x509 certificates?

Tags: mongodb, docker, x509, mongo-shell

I'm running a bash script called by Dockerfile.

I give my user the necessary permissions:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /home/mongod
```

I have one replica with 3 instances.

Before initiating this replica, I start the *mongod* process respective to each instance:

```
nohup gosu mongodb mongod --config /home/mongodb/instanceR0.conf
nohup gosu mongodb mongod --config /home/mongodb/instanceR1.conf
nohup gosu mongodb mongod --config /home/mongodb/instanceR2.conf
```

All the processes started successfully.

After, I want to connect to one of the instances in order to authenticate and initiate the replica set:

```
# connect to one db instance
nohup gosu mongodb mongo --port 57040 --ssl --host example.com --sslPEMKeyFile /home/mongodb/certificateExample.pem --sslCAFile /home/mongodb/caExample.pem

# authenticate with user
nohup gosu mongodb mongo "db.getSiblingDB('\$external').auth({ mechanism: 'MONGODB-X509', user: 'CN=example.com,OU=StackOverflow,O=Example,L=City,ST=City,C=PT' })"

# initiate replica sets
nohup gosu mongodb mongo "rs.initiate({ _id: 'replicaExample', members: [{ _id : 0, host : '127.0.0.1:57040' }, { _id : 1, host : '127.0.0.1:57041' }, { _id : 2, host : '127.0.0.1:57042' }] })"
```

The problem happens when *connecting to one db instance*. It connects successfully to the mongo shell but when executing *authenticate with user* it leaves the mongo shell.

```
connecting to: mongodb://example.com:57040/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb

Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("27eb0298-2766-4efb-8054-211e18c88ea8") }

MongoDB server version: 4.2.6

bye
```

How can I construct a bash script command which after connecting to a db instance, will continue inside the mongo shell and execute the 2 remaining commands (*authenticate with user* and *initiate replica sets*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Use `--eval` after the statement to run the javascript functions.

For example:

```
nohup gosu mongodb mongo --port 57040 --ssl --host example.com --sslPEMKeyFile /home/mongodb/certificateExample.pem --sslCAFile /home/mongodb/caExample.pem --eval "db.getSiblingDB('\$external').auth({ mechanism: 'MONGODB-X509', user: 'CN=example.com,OU=StackOverflow,O=Example,L=City,ST=City,C=PT' });rs.initiate({ _id: 'replicaExample', members: [{ _id : 0, host : '127.0.0.1:57040' }, { _id : 1, host : '127.0.0.1:57041' }, { _id : 2, host : '127.0.0.1:57042' }] })"
```